# memcache garbage cleanup/purge expired

Tags: caching, memcached

I am using memcache to store larger session data that is choking the MYSQL/PHP limitations.
One thing however, is that these may not be requested again, and hence the 'lazy' memcache purging may not work.

Im trying to determine if there is a function that will purge all expired caches without having to walk through all of them.

OR ... if memcache will only consume so much memory, and then purge the expired as needed to make room ..

Just looking for the most optimal way to handle these caches.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain `choking the MYSQL/PHP limitations.` I'm not really sure what that means.

Comment: Thank for the followup -- trying to put TOO much data into was causing MYSQL/PHP sessions to fail - so needed to move that set of data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One thing however, is that these may not be requested again, and hence
>   the 'lazy' memcache purging may not work.
>   Im trying to determine if there is a function that will purge all
>   expired caches without having to walk through all of them.

I'm not really sure what you mean by this. There is no need to purge stuff that is expired. If it is expired, it doesn't really count anymore. You won't get these results because they aren't valid anymore (expired).

> OR ... if memcache will only consume so much memory, and then purge
>   the expired as needed to make room ..

Well, if you have expired items, they will be overwritten, so I don't see what the issue is.

Lets say you have room for 2 key/value pairs. If you have one that is expired, and one that is used but not expired, and you need to save a third, you can. You don't need to actually purge anything, because it will remove the expired one.

Comment: Nanne -- thanks for the clarification.  I just wanted to make sure that these expired values were sticking around and consuming space.

Comment: Bottom line is: if the expire, they are free game. Mind you, unexpired stuff can be purged too! I'm really not sure using memcache as a session-provider is such a good idea

Comment: Nanne -- thanks .. its just for the large datasets that arent used that often, and the data is too big for the DB session mechanism.  I guess the alternative is to change the session store for those to file-based, but I am trying to think if we move to elesticcache (or similar) that this will allow the session info to be available regardless of webserver?

any other suggestions as to storing this session data would be awesomely appreciated

Comment: I'm not really sure: the thing is , I would be really hesitant to put your sessions in a mechanism that could just remove them if space gets smaller, but one that needs pre-defined memory. It just doens't feel right, because you need worst-case memoryspace as a default reserved for memcached, which sounds kinda sub-optimal. And if you hit your max mem, you'll loose sessions, which is ofcourse never good.

Comment: the sessions themselves are not in memcache .. just a blog of data key'd to the session.  But of course, as you mentioned, that could cause loss of data if the memcache needs to use it up.  But these are only cached for 5 minutes, and are sort of throw away data anyhows.

Comment: "If it is expired, it doesn't really count anymore." - that's not true, it still takes memory. It is taking memory until memcached memory is full and there's a need to add a new key. Only then are expired keys actually deleted.

Comment: it is not taking memory for any sane definition of memory. After deletion the memory is not 'returned' to the system or anything, so for all practical purposes expired and deleted keys are the same.

Comment: @Nanne "After deletion the memory is not 'returned' to the system" - exactly, the deleted records are still taking your system's memory. In redis for instance, deleted records are cleared periodically and RAM is freed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're arguing. it seems like you;re arguing about something you deem incorrect, but you also seem to agree with me. So to clarify: with "doesn't count" i meant that you don't need to purge expired keys. Purged, deleted and expired keys are all the same in this case, so you don't need to go from one to the other. If you need more system memory, you can do other things, but that's not what this question was about. My point was: you do not need to purge expired keys. That does not do anything.